How do I insert a tab character into a string in a clipboard-friendly way?
A string in Javascript can contain tab characters. I can see this in my text editor, and I can copy-and-paste it into my browser console and operate with it (e.g, perform Regex searches for it). When I tried to replace something in the string with the tab character, the string rendered the replacement as literal characters (e.g, \t). “No problem,” I thought; “it’s just the way the console renders stuff.” But when I copy-and-paste the return value shown by the console, I copy the literal characters (e.g, \ and t), not the expected tab.
I’ve tried:
"word word".replace(/\s/, " ") //=> "word\tword" (you can’t see it, but the "   " is a tab character copied from VS Code, and no, the console didn’t transform it to four spaces or \t immediately on paste.)

"word word".replace(/\s/, /\t/)   //=> "word\\tword"

"word word".replace(/\s/, "\t")   //=> "word\tword"

"word word".replace(/\s/, "&#9")  //=> "word&#9word"

"word word".replace(/\s/, "&#9;") //=> "word&#9;word"

"word word".replace(/\s/, &#9)    //=> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'

"word word".replace(/\s/, /&#9/)  //=> "word/&#9/word"

...but none of them yield a tab character that I can copy and paste between applications.

"\t" is the correct way to do it.

The second argument to replace() must be a string or function, not a regexp.

What's wrong with "word\tword" in the result? As you said, that's just how the console renders it. The TAB character is really there.

When I do console.log("word word".replace(/\s/, "\t")) in Chrome, it displays whitespace between the words, not literal \t. How are you seeing the \t?

@Barmar I was just letting the console display the operation’s return value. I didn’t think of logging it explicitly. Can you post that as an answer?

Use console.log() to log the result to the console, instead of just using the automatic printing of the expression value. This formats it rather than showing the syntax of a string literal.


console.log("word word".replace(/\s/, "\t"))



